# What is the reason PayPal is sending back a 400 Response Code, PAYEE_ACCOUNT_INVALID in Sandbox Mode?

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to implement payments using `paypal` and `nodejs`. So far I'm working with `paypal-rest-sdk` to work with the API calls. I wrote a code which I'm getting credit card info and then transferring them to `paypal` but I'm getting a `400 Response Code` codenamed as `PAYEE_ACCOUNT_INVALID`. There's seems to be a lot of issues like this however no one of them addressed the solution correctly.

What is the reason in this case? This is my `json` which I'm sending out:

```
// Construct a PayPal payment request
  const createPaymentJson = {
    intent: 'sale',
    payer: {

      payment_method: 'credit_card',

      funding_instruments: [
        {
          credit_card: {
            number: numericCardNumber, // Use the numeric card number without spaces
            type: "mastercard", // Card type (e.g., visa, mastercard), paymentData.cardType
            expire_month: paymentData.expiry.split(' / ')[0],
            expire_year: '20' + paymentData.expiry.split(' / ')[1], // Properly format the year
            cvv2: paymentData.cvv, // CVV code
          },
        },
      ],
    },

    
    
    transactions: [
      {
        amount: {
          total: paymentData.amount, // Extract the amount from the request body
          currency: paymentData.currency, // Extract the currency from the request body
        },
        description: paymentData.description, // Extract the description from the request body
      },
    ],

    redirect_urls: {
      return_url: process.env.PAYPAL_RETURN_URL,
      cancel_url: process.env.PAYPAL_CANCEL_URL,
    },

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The paypal-rest-sdk and the v1/payments API are both deprecated things that should not be used for any new integration.

To accept cards with PayPal use the [standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) or [advanced](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate/) integrations, with no SDK for the HTTPS API calls as none are supported.

Comment: So you mean there's not anymore any `checkout-sdk-js` for the v2/payments ??